# Issue in Converting multiple datetime format into single sql datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have tried to converting multiple date time formats into  datetime using SQL function , i am getting the result but there was a problem in specific format . I have attached code and expected result . Is there any way to resolve this issue

I have tried in SQL Server 2016

```
USE [db_Temp]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_viz_IsStartDateAA]
(
           @fromdate nvarchar(30)
)
RETURNS Datetime
AS
BEGIN
       -- Declare the return variable here
       DECLARE @ClearDate Datetime

               SET @ClearDate =  
               CASE WHEN ISDATE(@fromdate) = 1 THEN @fromdate 
              ELSE NULL END          

       -- Return the result of the function
       RETURN @ClearDate

END



-- Select query

SELECT [DateFormat] AS [Date format],
          [SourceDate] AS [Source date],
          [dbo].[udf_viz_IsStartDateAA]([SourceDate]) AS [Start date]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_SourceDate]
```

The expected result is “2019-06-03 00:00:00.000” 
but the actual result is “2019-03-06 00:00:00.000”

Comment: Please don't post links to off site resources for your data. Post the data in your  in your post. Also, I suggest against `ISDATE`, use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`. Finally, `yyyy-MM-dd` (or `yyyy-dd-MM`) isn't an ambiguous date format when using the `datetime` datatype. For example, for me on my instance, `CONVERT(datetime,'2019-06-03')` will return the date `20190306`.

Comment: There's no SQL server function that allows the date format mask in the way you need, but [this might help](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date)

Comment: If you are storing data in the format `yyyy-dd-MM` and `yyyy-MM-dd` and you have no way of knowing which, then your data has lost all meaning, and unfortunately is now useless to you. This is, I'm afraid, one way of learning why choosing the correct data type is so important, and why choosing the wrong one is such a bad idea.

Comment: As for a reason why `ISDATE` is a bad function, here is one reason: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=901fdccf496a47bc773370e2248c8f7f). Notice that only one function returns a value, however, both could be converted using the style codes `101` and `103` respectively. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2f5fcfe939dc9b59b123cadc74003de)

Answer (score 0):

Sql server can not infer date format just from the text value. It can not tell '06032019' is June,3  or  March,6 just from the text.  If no explicit style  provided for `convert`, server applies the style according to session settings  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql

Good habit is always deal with date-representing strings with explicit `convert` and style.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that all yoru dates are in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss`, then there's no need to a user-defined function. SQL Server has `CONVERT` and `TRY_CONVERT` which accepts [style codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles):

```
SELECT [DateFormat] AS [Date format],
       [SourceDate] AS [Source date],
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime,STUFF([SourceDate],11,1,'T'),126) AS [Start date]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_SourceDate];
```

I also used `STUFF` here though to change the `' '` to a `'T'` (as the ISo format uses a T rather than a white space).

Comment: OP specifically highlighted that they have US and non-US formats stored as string (among others), as defined by the format string in the next column. Well, they did until you told them off for providing a link

Comment: Considering the OP gave no example data apart from one example @JohnHC this was impossible to infer.